# Timing a DNS lookup

Tags: windows-7, dns, timing

I am trying to time DNS resolutions on a Windows 7 machine. I have downloaded the "DIG" tool for windows, but there is no inherent timing available. The other thing i have is powershell, im unable to find a command that returns the time to resolve the DN to a host address.

Any ideas?

Note: This is for a university project, not just a one off address. I am going to be collecting data for hundreds (probably) of DNS lookups.

Comment: Are you going to test the DNS servers or individual websites?

Comment: Individual websites. My hypothesis is that it takes longer to resolve the domain name of a US webpage over a UK one. Whilst i know this is utter crap because they could be hosted anywhere etc... I jump through a necessary hoop

Comment: To answer your question properly, i have a list of the most visited webpages, both for UK and US domains. I am going to time the DNS lookup of each domain.

Answer (score 0):

Do this in a Linux VM. Linux is free and so is VMWare Player. Then you can get your statistics running something like `time dig superuser.com`.

As a student you should be using Linux anyway!

Comment: I had thought i might resort to this, do you know what the smallest version of Linux is?

Comment: Puppy Linux. :) It's about 100 MiB.